# What to do when circling restrictions conflict with VFR traffic pattern direction

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, traffic-pattern, circling-approach

At 4B8 (Robertson Field) there is a single published IAP: RNAV (GPS) 2.

For VFR traffic, the field is left traffic on both Rwy 2 and Rwy 20. However, there are large obstacles to the east of the field, so the RNAV procedure indicates “Circling NA east of Rwy 2-20. Circling Rwy 20 NA at night”. Certainly seems reasonable given the obstacles.

My question is: in practice is it possible to land here using Rwy 20 at all (during the day) without committing a violation while flying under IFR. I.e. if you follow the RNAV 2 approach, and you want to circle to land Rwy 20, the IAP requires you to circle west of the field (which would have you making right traffic). That doesn’t sound legal or fun for a field that is left traffic otherwise.

Of course you could break out high enough to cancel IFR and then make left traffic (to the east of the field but inside of the obstacles). But that clearly isn’t practical for a low IFR day. Is this field simply unusable for IFR traffic when the winds are from the south?

Comment: In this case there is no alternate runway (other than the reciprocal). So I guess the question is somewhat more pointed here. If right traffic to 20 is not allowed, then the only available IFR runway here is 2.